# stop submitting a form with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, geocode

hello I am trying to stop the submitting of the process with jquery but it doesn't work.

Here is the current code of the submission process. There should be no submission when false is returned.

```
function validateinput(gu) {

var geocoder= new google.maps.Geocoder();
var address = $(gu).find("input[name=autocomplete]").val();


geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address, 
  componentRestrictions: {
      country: 'DE'
    }}, function(results, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {

      if(!results[1]){


          $.each(results[0].address_components, function(){

          if(this.types[0] == "street_number"){ street_number = this.long_name; }
          if(this.types[0] == "route"){ route = this.long_name; }
          if(this.types[0] == "administrative_area_level_1"){ administrative_area_level_1 = this.long_name; }
          if(this.types[0] == "postal_code"){ postal_code = this.long_name; }

          });


    if(typeof(street_number) !== "undefined" && street_number !== null && street_number !== '') {
      $(gu).find("input[name=street_number]").val(street_number);
      $(gu).find("input[name=route]").val(route);
      $(gu).find("input[name=administrative_area_level_1]").val(administrative_area_level_1);
      $(gu).find("input[name=postal_code]").val(postal_code);
      $(gu).find("input[name=lat]").val(results[0].geometry.location.lat());
      $(gu).find("input[name=lng]").val(results[0].geometry.location.lng());
return true;
    }else{

      $(gu).find("input[name=autocomplete]").val(administrative_area_level_1 + ", " + route + " ");
      $(gu).find("input[name=autocomplete]").focus();
      $(gu).find('span.addr_error').html('Bitte gebe deine Hausnr. an.');
return false;

    }


      }else{

      $(gu).find("input[name=autocomplete]").focus();
      $(gu).find('span.addr_error').html('Bitte wähle deine Lieferadresse.');
return false;



      }



    }else {
      $(gu).find("input[name=autocomplete]").focus();
      $(gu).find('span.addr_error').html('Wir konnten deine Adresse nicht finden.');
return false;

  });

}


$("#aadress-form").submit(function(){ return validateinput(this) });
$("#ladress-form").submit(function(){ return validateinput(this) });
```

How do I stop submitting the form? Sorry for my bad English I hope you understand my problem and will help me.

Comment: `geocoder.geocode()` method is async, you should return `false` from `validateinput()` and only submit `form` if needed, using e.g `gu.submit();` (in place in your code of `return true;`)

Comment: Thank you it works perfectly,

Answer (score 0):

you can stop fomr submission by doing this.

```
$("#aadress-form").submit(function(e){e.preventDefault(); return validateinput(this) });
$("#ladress-form").submit(function(e){ e.preventDefault(); return validateinput(this) });
```

Comment: thank you for your anwer but  A. Wolff´s solutin in the comment fixed the problem already